# Take a photo with custom camera resolution?

Tags: android, camera, photo

I am writing an app that allows to take photo with the default camera. The problem is that the photo are sending to a server, so I have to reduce them size. (for example from 3 mb to 1 mb)
this is how i take a photo:

```
public void startCameraActivity() {

    Intent imageIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());


    File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "path");
    imagesFolder.mkdirs();

    //String filePath = "path" + timeStamp + ".jpg" ;
    File image = new File(imagesFolder, "path" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    Uri uriSavedImage = Uri.fromFile(image);

    nomeFileJpg = "path"+timeStamp+".jpg";
    Log.i(TAG,"Nome del file: "+nomeFileJpg);

    imageIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
    startActivityForResult(imageIntent, 2);

}
```

How can I add to reduce the dimension?

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the resolution by telling the Android Camera directly. Have a look at [Android Camera.Size](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Size.html) for more info. To do this safely, you might also find [Camera.Preferences.getSupportedPictureSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes%28%29) useful.

Comment: Those methods are available if you accessing hardware camera in your code, where @penny89 is using built in camera app so he didn't even have references to camera object to customize it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think if that is possible because i don't think if any of those built in camera apps have functions to obtain such parameters from intent that started them.
I had the same problem while developing my app. Remember that default camera app differs on devices, for example there were issues with obtaining path of taken picture or some of those default camera apps you couldn't obtain thumbnails.
So my suggestion is to try create your own camera app or use free library that will allow you to adjust certain parameters. [camera library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera)